# What is the equivalent of locales-all from Debian?

Tags: package-management, debian, locale

On Debian, I can have a package depend on `locales-all` to ensure that all locales are installed/available. There is no such package in Ubuntu.

It used to have `belocs-locales-*` which appeared to do the same; alternatively, one could depend on various localisation packs (e.g. just `de`+`en`+`fr` for most of Western Europe, which is of limited use; sometimes, software does in fact require all standard locales). These packages disappeared between hardy and precise, AFAICT.

So, what Ubuntu package can I `Depends` on to have all locales available?

Edit: this is *not* the same as the `locales` package, which merely provides data files needed to generate the locales; merely installing the `locales-all` package in Debian makes those locales available immediately, and all of them. (It contains a pack, in recent versions, saving much space too.) This way, the user does not have a knob in which they can (accidentally) disable necessary locales.

Comment: I don't think there is an equivalent in Ubuntu. One reason why locales-all is not included in the Ubuntu archive might be that it would conflict with the way Ubuntu's langpack system deals with locale creation (but that's just a guess). Out of curiosity: What kind of program would need instant access to all supported locales?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson several kinds of webapps: I know one that uses system locales for server-side i18n, and I know one that has unexplainable failures that just go away when installing `locales-all`. My current "trigger to ask" is a package containing stuff that depends on one specific locale, but using `locales` is out of the question because other packages or the local admin can disable the locale later, if I enable it using e.g. debconf settings.

Comment: There’s now [an open bug about this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glibc/+bug/1394929).

Comment: Noticed. I added a task for _langpack-locales_, which I think is the proper Ubuntu package.

Answer (score 5):

I found the following solution on https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Table_of_locales

```
   sudo ln -s /usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED /var/lib/locales/supported.d/all
   sudo locale-gen
```

Comment: Possibly, yes. But I cannot do this in a package. (See above: without the user being able to disable this again (except by uninstalling my package or locales-all).) Maybe needs `ln -sf`, too…

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm reading your wrong, this is just `locales` now.

It's part of the `minimal^` task requirements as well as by `ubuntu-minimal` directly so this should *always* be installed. You shouldn't need to depend on anything to guarantee its presence but if you *need* something, pick `ubuntu-minimal` or something else you need that also depends on `ubuntu-minimal`. That's a pretty sane default.

---

Looking at [the contents of Debian's `locales-all`](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/amd64/locales-all/filelist) I can see a lot of files like this that *aren't* in the standard Ubuntu `locales` package (see `dpkg -L locales`):

```
/usr/lib/locale/am_ET/LC_ADDRESS
/usr/lib/locale/am_ET/LC_COLLATE
/usr/lib/locale/am_ET/LC_CTYPE
/usr/lib/locale/am_ET/LC_IDENTIFICATION
/usr/lib/locale/am_ET/LC_MEASUREMENT
/usr/lib/locale/am_ET/LC_MESSAGES/SYS_LC_MESSAGES
/usr/lib/locale/am_ET/LC_MONETARY
/usr/lib/locale/am_ET/LC_NAME
/usr/lib/locale/am_ET/LC_NUMERIC
/usr/lib/locale/am_ET/LC_PAPER
/usr/lib/locale/am_ET/LC_TELEPHONE
/usr/lib/locale/am_ET/LC_TIME
```

I [searched packages.ubuntu.com for similar files](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=LC_TIME&mode=&suite=trusty&arch=any) and couldn't find any. This means they're either not packaged, they've got drastically different names, or they extract on install (rare but possible).

The only exception I can see are the locales installed by `libc-bin` into `/usr/lib/locale/C.UTF-8/`.

---

Ooo, I might have been on the money with the extraction. The `locales` package includes a `locale-gen` application which generates these sorts of files. See [the wiki for more information on locales](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale).

Comment: Just the `locales` package is **not** enough – true, with `locale-gen` I could generate specific locales, but this does not replace `locales-all` which makes *all* of them available **without** the need to run an extra command (and **without** the user being able to then manually disable those locales again). This is true in Debian as well.

Answer (score 0):

I know that's an old question, but did you try install all language packs through apt-get? I could solve a similar problem where I would need lots of different locales in a server and solved it running `sudo apt-get install language-pack-*`. It downloaded all the files (about 2GB when finished unpacking) and generated all the available locales.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not a consistent solution, especially as I need to express it as package dependency, not as interactive thing, and a language pack is much more than just the locales.